# How to specify permament columns for music folder in Windows10?

Tags: windows, desktop-customization, desktop.ini

When I create folder with MP3 files Windows changes folder template to "Music". Ok, but default columns for this template are: Name, #, Title, Artists, Album. I can customize that for one folder by adding/removing columns and later go to folder options and apply my settings to all folders of this type. Then it works for all of my music folders on hard disc I did that on. I would like to set such settings permament for specific folders, to make it works even if I move such folder to another disc or even computer (now I would need to customize and save all settings again for each hard disc/computer I put folder on). Is there any option to make my folder to be displayed by all Windows systems by default in the way I specified? Something like I customized folder icons by using system folders, desktop.ini and own .ico files, so it works even if I have my music folders on USB drive used with different computers.

Answer (score 0):

Regrettably, the folder type (General items, Video, Music, etc.) is *not* stored in the hidden desktop.ini files (though icon displayed in Explorer info tip, etc. *are*), but rather, in the extended NTFS properties. AFAIK, the columns selected for display (e.g., date modified, composers, frame width)  are *also* stored in the NTFS metadata. This information is *definitely not* transferred when a folder is copied to a different file system such as ext4 or exFAT, since those systems do not support those extended file attributes.

In fact, in my tests, that metadata is not copied on moving a folder (e.g. of type Music), to a folder of a different type (e.g. Documents). Instead, as you've found, the copied folder acquires the attributes of its new parent.

The only work-around I know is to move folders to another *folder of the same type*. If this is on another machine, then the folder types on *that* PC must be set to display corresponding fields. For example, I have all Pictures folders on all my PC's set to display Camera model. Displaying the NTFS extended attributes in Linux is possible, but nontrivial; see also this [second article in the series](https://medium.com/@stdout_/accessing-ntfs-extended-attributes-from-linux-part-2-630d83c3b4f8) and [this one](https://linux.goeszen.com/extended-file-attributes-on-your-filesystem-how-to-enable-and-use-them.html).